# How to deal with spoilers at work?

Tags: colleagues

As many of you may know, episodes of Game Of Thrones are coming every Sunday night in the USA, which means Monday really early in France.

The trouble here is that some watch the episode either during lunch break or really early in the morning and they start to talk about it.

Since I watch the episode on Monday after work, I think it's pretty annoying. These people are from a different department and I have no clue on how I could tell them not to spoil without sounding like "Don't ever talk about shows near me".

And since a lot of people talk about it, it's pretty hard to go to all of them individually and say "Don't spoil anything at work".

**Is there a way to let people know I don't want them to talk about the episode in front of me at the coffee break?**

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I agree with you, but since there's more than "just those two here" it's pretty difficult to go see everyone and ask "Do you watch GoT ? Yes ? Don't talk about it" since it's never the same people (or not always the same) talking about it near the coffee machine

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with navigating the workplace.

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 Well I think it does, if it were friends (or always the same colleagues) I know how I should deal with it, if it's random people at the coffee machine it's harder to deal with, except if I put a sign "DO NOT SPOIL" on the coffee machine maybe

Comment: @sh5164 It isn't really any different from random strangers in the bus talking about it, and the "solution" is perhaps the same: do something which prevents you from hearing what they are saying.

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 Yet in a bus you can put listeners on, harder to do at the break room

Comment: Well I guess I'll close it, since I might have no answer professionally related because of the subject.

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 I'd say this is on-topic here. The workplace environment gives you options that you don't have on the bus. The question of what those options are and whether it makes sense to use them seems answerable and within scope.

Comment: @sh5164 I've undeleted your answer since I think you're jumping the gun here. MaskedMan raises a good point that this *could* be off-topic here but we generally let close votes determine that which requires multiple users to weigh in. I'd recommend leaving this up and awaiting further input instead of just deleting it. That said, your question could probably use an edit to focus more on a specific strategy or to ask about possible options to address the specific question of getting people to stop discussing spoilers rather than "dealing with them".

Comment: @Lilienthal It's just I'm afraid that since it's about spoilers people might think it won't be serious enough for a workplace matter

Comment: This isn't nearly the least serious workplace matter I've seen asked about (and answered properly) on this site, so I wouldn't worry too much about that.

Comment: Sorry, can't read your question, because I am afraid of GoT spoilers. :)

Comment: Put in your finger in your ears and yell "LA LA LA LA LA LA". BTW people take series serious and I am sure something like spoiler could become a huge workplace issue if it is not respected. This seems very on-topic to me.

Comment: Are you allowed to work with music and earbuds?

Comment: Loudly saying "Spoilers!" Seems to be universally understood as A polite "stfu plz".

Comment: or - get over being spoiled - if a spoiler ruins a story for you - it wasn't a good story imo. The best tales are ones that are up for repeat interactions. For example: Fight Club has a great twist that was fun the first time, but it is stands up even once you know what is happening, possibly even more so #twocents

Comment: Agree, this is a perfectly valid question. It's an issue that genuinely comes up.  I voted to leave open and will vote to reopen as soon as it closes.

Comment: Ok, let's see ... the question is allegedly on-topic, and the answers we have received so far are: 1. "Please don't talk about GoT near me." 2. Leave them alone. 3. Filter out the conversations that you don't want to hear. All of these are strategies to implement the basic principle I pointed out above "do something which prevents you from hearing what they are saying", and each of these can be employed while travelling with random strangers on my hypothetical bus. So please enlighten me again, what is the workplace-specific issue here? Maybe I am stupid, but I just don't see it.

Comment: I'm sorry you can't see it. I'm not going to explain it you.

Answer (score 2):

It will be impossible (as you have mentioned) to influence everyone at your workplace to guard their conversations around you. So knowing that, it now becomes your responsibility to filter the conversations that come your way.

If it means so much to you, you will likely have to sacrifice time in the break room to avoid hearing something you don't want to hear. It's your preference, not theirs, so you're the one that is responsible to take action.

If you're in a group gathering before a meeting (for example), you may not be able to avoid the conversations starting. If this happens and you see that a spoiler might be about to pop up, you can simply say,

> Wait, I haven't watched it, yet. Don't spoil it for me!

You might have to leave the room for a minute if they insist on talking about it.

Comment: I don't think the comparison works. I don't drink alcohol with colleagues, but I have no issues with going to a happy hour gathering, because their drinks don't affect me. Maybe "joining a smoke break" is a better comparison, if those things still exist.